# How to read attribute data from the object returned from FB.api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have the following code implement to catch the event when a user leaves a comment. It is firing correctly, but the problem is I have no idea how to parse the object that is being passed to my callback function.

```
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({ appId: '<myAppId>', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true });
        FB.Event.subscribe('comment.create', function () {
            FB.api('/comments/?ids=http://foo.com', function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            });
        });
    };
    (function () {
        var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
        e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
    } ());
</script>
```

Looking at the console log in firebug, `console.log(response)` shows this object:

```
{
    "http://foo.com": {
       "data": [
          {
             "id": "10150090820621770_15631060",
             "from": {
                "name": "Test User",
                "id": "1234455"
             },
             "message": "testing",
             "created_time": "2011-04-18T01:55:38+0000"
          },
          {
             "id": "10150090820621770_15631066",
             "from": {
                "name": "Test UserToo",
                "id": "1149043581"
             },
             "message": "testing2",
             "created_time": "2011-04-18T01:56:12+0000"
          }
       ]
    }
 }
```

However, if I try to access the object with `response.data[0].from.name` I get `undefined` returned.  Additionally, all the following return `undefined` also:

- `response.data`
- `response.data.length`
- `response.data[0]`

I have no idea how to parse the object to read the attributes. Anyone have any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forget your "http://foo.com" ..
So it should be something like `response["http://foo.com"].data[0].id`
Or `response["http://foo.com"].data[0].from.name`

Answer (score 0):

I think the response is text.  You need to get the compiler to parse the text into a javascript object.  since the text is formatted as JSON, that's pretty easy.  on browsers that support JSON (the wikipedia page says: ff 3.5+, IE8+, opera 10.5+, webkit based stuff), you can do the following:

```
var responseObject = JSON.parse(response);
```

that should get you the object you want.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the [FQL](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/comment/) to access FB comments.